# TSQL Cursor automatically rounds up money type variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't know why this code output 0.34 (I expected 0.335).
Does TSQL cursor automatically round up money type variables?
Please help me who knows about this.

```
DECLARE @Rate MONEY;

DECLARE csrRate
CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 0.335

OPEN csrRate;
FETCH NEXT FROM
    csrRate
INTO
    @Rate

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @Rate

        FETCH NEXT FROM csrRate INTO @Rate
    END
CLOSE csrRate
DEALLOCATE csrRate
```

Comment: well traditionally, money has 2 digits after the decimal point! Also: don't use the MONEY datatype!

Comment: Try with `DECLARE csrRate CURSOR FOR SELECT CAST('0.335' AS MONEY);`?

Comment: @MitchWheat The `MONEY` datatype in SQL Server stores 4 digits. In SSMS it also *shows* up to 4 digits.

Comment: Print implicitly casts it to a string. You see the same with "Select cast( cast(0.335 as money) as varchar)". You can use convert with style 2 to avoid this.

Comment: @TT: I know what it stores.

Comment: @MitchWheat Thank you very much. I will use DECIMAL datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behavior when `PRINT` is used. It cast the `money` to `string`. And the [default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) is:

[image]

So, you can cast it like this:

```
DECLARE @Rate MONEY;

DECLARE csrRate
CURSOR FOR
    SELECT $0.335

OPEN csrRate;
FETCH NEXT FROM
    csrRate
INTO
    @Rate

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        PRINT @Rate
        PRINT convert(varchar(30), @Rate, 2)
        --SELECT @RATE


        FETCH NEXT FROM csrRate INTO @Rate
    END
CLOSE csrRate
DEALLOCATE csrRate
```

Also, if you try to `SELECT` the value, it is not cast to string.

Comment: Now I know it's very dangerous to use `PRINT` for debugging. I will cast or use `SELECT` alternatively.